# Regex Matching - A letter not preceded by another letter

Tags: python, regex

What could be regex which match `anystring` followed by `daily` but it must not match `daily` preceded by `m`?

For example it should match following string

- `beta.daily`
- `abcdaily`
- `dailyabc`
- `daily`

But it must not match

- `mdaily` or
- `abcmdaily` or
- `mdailyabc`

I have tried following and other regex but failed each time:

- `r'[^m]daily'`: But it doesn't match with `daily`
- `r'[^m]?daily'` : It match with string containing `mdaily` which is not intended

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add a negative lookbehind, `(?<!m)d`, before `daily`:

```
(?<!m)daily
```

The zero width negative lookbehind, `(?<!m)`, makes sure `daily` is not preceded by `m`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJ8mV5/1)